# jQuery - Given a TextArea Val()- How to get everything before the first line break

Tags: jquery

I have a text area that allows for returns (enter key). I'd like to know how to get everything in the textarea that is before the first linebreak/return/enter key?

Should I use something like split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could split on the line break, and get the first item in the resulting Array.

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    alert( this.value.split('\n')[0] );
});
```

Not sure if this is needed, but you could use a regular expression that includes `\r` as well.

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    alert( this.value.split(/\n|\r/)[0] );
});
```

Comment: thanks, will accept once the 10m pass and Stackoverflow allows me 2